# CSS Setting pseudo class width and height with grid-area and calc

Tags: css, hover, css-animations, css-grid, mousehover

I found a neat CSS [animation](https://codepen.io/cassidoo/pen/RZOWQb?editors=1100) I want to use that gives an element a hover effect.

I'm having issues trying to tailor it to my use-case.

I have my page layout using grid in a 3x3 but there are only 5 main elements which I space out to take additional vertical/horizontal space (that's why you'll see some duplicate `grid-template-areas` names of everything but `middle`).

```
body {
  margin: 0.3rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "topLeft topMid topMid"
    "topLeft middle midRight"
    "bottomLeft bottomLeft midRight";
}
```

Here is what it looks like:
[image]

In the code snippet from the [codepen](https://codepen.io/cassidoo/pen/RZOWQb?editors=1100) it specifies a `width` and `height` in `px`. So attempting to make it work for my webpage I tried to replaced `width` and `height` with `grid-area` in place of `width` and `height: calc(90vh / 3)` in place of `height` with `px` but that's not working.

My question is for the `width` can I pass in `calc(grid-area: middle)`? I've tried it but I may be doing something incorrectly. Or is there a better way for me to do this?

Basically, I want the width on these `pseudo` classes to be the size of my `grid-area: middle` and the `height: calc(90vh /3)` (which I think works).

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0.3rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "topLeft topMid topMid"
    "topLeft middle midRight"
    "bottomLeft bottomLeft midRight";
}

.tile {
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  margin: 0.3rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#experience,
/* #about, */
#work {
  height: calc(90vh / 3);
}

#skills {
  grid-area: topLeft;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#stack {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#stack.hide {
  display: none;
}

#experience {
  grid-area: topMid;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#listOfExp {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#listOfExp.hide {
  display: none;
}

#about {
  grid-area: middle;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  /* move #about back to line 26 if this doesn't work */
  height: calc(90vh / 3);

  /* animation */
  position: relative;
  transition: 1s box-shadow;
}

#about:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 35px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

#about:hover::before,
#about:hover::after {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;

  /* need height and width */
  /* width: 250px;
      height: 250px; */
  /* grid-area: calc(middle);
  height: calc(90vh / 3); */

  background: #fda8cf;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  z-index: -1;
  animation: 1s clockwise infinite;
}

#about:hover:after {
  background: #f3ce5e;
  animation: 2s counterclockwise infinite;
}

#cheng {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#cheng.hide {
  display: none;
}

#work {
  grid-area: bottomLeft;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#works {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#works.hide {
  display: none;
}

#contact {
  grid-area: midRight;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#contactMe {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#contactMe.hide {
  display: none;
}

@keyframes clockwise {
  0% {
    top: -5px;
    left: 0;
  }
  12% {
    top: -2px;
    left: 2px;
  }
  25% {
    top: 0;
    left: 5px;
  }
  37% {
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
  }
  50% {
    top: 5px;
    left: 0;
  }
  62% {
    top: 2px;
    left: -2px;
  }
  75% {
    top: 0;
    left: -5px;
  }
  87% {
    top: -2px;
    left: -2px;
  }
  100% {
    top: -5px;
    left: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes counterclockwise {
  0% {
    top: -5px;
    right: 0;
  }
  12% {
    top: -2px;
    right: 2px;
  }
  25% {
    top: 0;
    right: 5px;
  }
  37% {
    top: 2px;
    right: 2px;
  }
  50% {
    top: 5px;
    right: 0;
  }
  62% {
    top: 2px;
    right: -2px;
  }
  75% {
    top: 0;
    right: -5px;
  }
  87% {
    top: -2px;
    right: -2px;
  }
  100% {
    top: -5px;
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body id="main">
  <div id="skills" class="tile">
    <h2>skills</h2>
    <div id="stack" class="hide">
      <p>here's my tech stack</p>
      <p>HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Python, jQuery</p>
      <p>React, Node, Express</p>
      <p>SQL, MySQL, NoSQL, MongoDB, Sequelize, Mongoose</p>
      <p>REST APIs</p>
      <p>Git, cURL, GitHub, GitLab, Heroku, Jira, ServiceNow, Confluence</p>
      <p>Shopify Liquid</p>
      <p>various npm packages</p>
      <p>and always adding more...</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="experience" class="tile">
    <h2>experience</h2>
    <div id="listOfExp" class="hide">
      <p>experiences share who we all are. here are some of mine.</p>
      <p>i've been a project manager for various technologies and business processes working along side cross-functional
        teams.</p>
      <p>i've contributed with dev teams using the agile approach and methodologies.</p>
      <p>i'm a subject matter expert in order management systems and fraud in ecommerce.</p>
      <p>i love using data to tell stories and in the decision making process.</p>
      <p>i've been an entrepreneur!</p>
      <p>i've lead teams as a manager, coach, and menter.</p>
      <p>check out my resume here!</p>

      <!-- link to resume here -->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="about" class="tile">
    <h1>Cheng</h1>
    <div id="cheng" class="hide">
      <h3>hi. my name is Cheng.</h3>
      <p>i'm a software developer.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="work" class="tile">
    <h2>work</h2>
    <div id=works class="hide">
      <p>here are some things i've worked on.</p>

      <!-- cards for each works goes here -->
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="contact" class="tile">
    <h2>contact me</h2>
    <div id="contactMe" class="hide">
      <p>here's how you can get a hold of me.</p>
      <p>send me an email at cheng21tang@gmail.com</p>
      <!-- email icon here -->
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="./assets/js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please put a complete snippet into your question, not in an image.

Comment: No problem. I put the code snippets in there.

Comment: Can you just calculate the width? It would seem to be 100vw / 3 minus some margins (and any grid gaps or borders).

Comment: Yes, that does work! Thanks so much. I wasn't even thinking about just setting it to the grid calculation that I knew it would be which was the `100vw / 3`. Thank you!